# serilog cant add custom property to database table

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

using this serilog config and it logs to database fine but decided to save clientip as new column,

installed Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo package.

it saves client ip to properties column as a inner text, but I expected to save it to clientip column in table.

appsettingsjson:

```
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo" ],
    "Enrich": [ "WithClientIp", "WithClientAgent" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "Server= ...",
          "tableName": "Log"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

API:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        Log.Information("This is your Ip: {ClientIp}");
```

Program.cs:

```
public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; } = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
            .CreateLogger();

            try
            {
                Log.Information("Getting the motors running...");
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want extra columns, you need to [configure them](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver#custom-property-columns).

```json
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo" ],
    "Enrich": [ "WithClientIp", "WithClientAgent" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "Server= ...",
          "tableName": "Log",
          "columnOptionsSection": {
            "additionalColumns" [
              {
                "ColumnName": "ClientIp",
                "PropertyName": "ClientIp",
                "DataType": "varchar",
                "DataLength": 45
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```